# android in app purchase subscription purchase token returning null value

Tags: android

I have implemented in app purchase module in my app and i want my app to perform auto renew subscription for users for that i have code well for that.

The problem is that when i purchase a subscription google play sends me a notifyid through which i get purchase history but in that purchase history i m getting purchase response "null".Is there a way to get purchase response for a subscription and also let me know how google play notify us after auto 
renew of subscription.

I m attaching below code where i m getting purchase response in JSON format.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.surfwise.inapppurchase.Constans.PurchaseState;
import com.surfwise.inapppurchase.util.Base64;
import com.surfwise.inapppurchase.util.Base64DecoderException;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * Security-related methods. For a secure implementation, all of this code
 * should be implemented on a server that communicates with the application on
 * the device. For the sake of simplicity and clarity of this example, this code
 * is included here and is executed on the device. If you must verify the
 * purchases on the phone, you should obfuscate this code to make it harder for
 * an attacker to replace the code with stubs that treat all purchases as
 * verified.
 */
public class Security {
    private static final String TAG = "Security";

    private static final String KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withRSA";
    private static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

    /**
     * This keeps track of the nonces that we generated and sent to the server.
     * We need to keep track of these until we get back the purchase state and
     * send a confirmation message back to Android Market. If we are killed and
     * lose this list of nonces, it is not fatal. Android Market will send us a
     * new "notify" message and we will re-generate a new nonce. This has to be
     * "static" so that the {@link BillingReceiver} can check if a nonce exists.
     */
    private static HashSet<Long> sKnownNonces = new HashSet<Long>();

    /**
     * A class to hold the verified purchase information.
     */
    public static class VerifiedPurchase {
        public PurchaseState purchaseState;
        public String notificationId;
        public String productId;
        public String orderId;
        public long purchaseTime;
        public String developerPayload;
        public String purchaseToken;

        public VerifiedPurchase(PurchaseState purchaseState,
                String notificationId, String productId, String orderId,
                long purchaseTime, String developerPayload,String purchaseToken) {
            this.purchaseState = purchaseState;
            this.notificationId = notificationId;
            this.productId = productId;
            this.orderId = orderId;
            this.purchaseTime = purchaseTime;
            this.developerPayload = developerPayload;
            this.purchaseToken=purchaseToken;
        }
    }

    /** Generates a nonce (a random number used once). */
    public static long generateNonce() {
        long nonce = RANDOM.nextLong();
        sKnownNonces.add(nonce);
        return nonce;
    }

    public static void removeNonce(long nonce) {
        sKnownNonces.remove(nonce);
    }

    public static boolean isNonceKnown(long nonce) {
        return sKnownNonces.contains(nonce);
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the data was signed with the given signature, and returns
     * the list of verified purchases. The data is in JSON format and contains a
     * nonce (number used once) that we generated and that was signed (as part
     * of the whole data string) with a private key. The data also contains the
     * {@link PurchaseState} and product ID of the purchase. In the general
     * case, there can be an array of purchase transactions because there may be
     * delays in processing the purchase on the backend and then several
     * purchases can be batched together.
     * 
     * @param signedData
     *            the signed JSON string (signed, not encrypted)
     * @param signature
     *            the signature for the data, signed with the private key
     */
    public static ArrayList<VerifiedPurchase> verifyPurchase(String signedData,
            String signature) {
        if (signedData == null) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "data is null");
            return null;
        }
        if (Constans.DEBUG) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "signedData: " + signedData);
        }
        boolean verified = false;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
            /**
             * Compute your public key (that you got from the Android Market
             * publisher site).
             * 
             * Instead of just storing the entire literal string here embedded
             * in the program, construct the key at runtime from pieces or use
             * bit manipulation (for example, XOR with some other string) to
             * hide the actual key. The key itself is not secret information,
             * but we don't want to make it easy for an adversary to replace the
             * public key with one of their own and then fake messages from the
             * server.
             * 
             * Generally, encryption keys / passwords should only be kept in
             * memory long enough to perform the operation they need to perform.
             */
            String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuKgldGQPL/xV9WKLmY62UVgEm7gsPI/T/nQxRKpYN17m8Sq3gO9nWD17wXew4oNaHmMAmArS7s7eFi3Z+XiyWil1iZvEOdBOdZD502BzujPoBa4Fu9eITPBO9tzBEdvNLXf8amnsRj53TA4bcxB2O6OcXrQIv3t3n5Dg5Nn+rJpoKSNUv7NEzJagG/2NhyjIysAObbvQ5SBQ5NgRtZlvhsTeQJPMLhRAoRcTK/+47VkhrxM3PppeGjoNRryn6d+RhMjs/nydvoQtP2V76UcUu4m+daDnK3PxOnwLt50hNtQhNf3VgixVrSKfHUWp240uEz9MHstjj8BWPH9BFF/TewIDAQAB";
            PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey);
            verified = Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
            if (!verified) {
                //Log.w(TAG, "signature does not match data.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        JSONObject jObject;
        JSONArray jTransactionsArray = null;
        int numTransactions = 0;
        long nonce = 0L;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(signedData);

            // The nonce might be null if the user backed out of the buy page.
            nonce = jObject.optLong("nonce");
            jTransactionsArray = jObject.optJSONArray("orders");
            if (jTransactionsArray != null) {
                numTransactions = jTransactionsArray.length();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!Security.isNonceKnown(nonce)) {
            //Log.w(TAG, "Nonce not found: " + nonce);
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList<VerifiedPurchase> purchases = new ArrayList<VerifiedPurchase>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < numTransactions; i++) {
                JSONObject jElement = jTransactionsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("response--------------->"+jElement);
                int response = jElement.getInt("purchaseState");
                PurchaseState purchaseState = PurchaseState.valueOf(response);
                String productId = jElement.getString("productId");
                String packageName = jElement.getString("packageName");
                long purchaseTime = jElement.getLong("purchaseTime");
                String orderId = jElement.optString("orderId","");
                String notifyId = null;
                String purchaseToken=jElement.optString("purchaseToken",null);
                if (jElement.has("notificationId")) {
                    notifyId = jElement.getString("notificationId");
                }
                String developerPayload = jElement.optString(
                        "developerPayload",null);

                // If the purchase state is PURCHASED, then we require a
                // verified nonce.
                if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED && !verified) {
                    continue;
                }
                purchases.add(new VerifiedPurchase(purchaseState, notifyId,
                        productId, orderId, purchaseTime, developerPayload,purchaseToken));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "JSON exception: ", e);
            return null;
        }
        removeNonce(nonce);
        return purchases;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a PublicKey instance from a string containing the
     * Base64-encoded public key.
     * 
     * @param encodedPublicKey
     *            Base64-encoded public key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if encodedPublicKey is invalid
     */
    public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
        try {
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory
                    .getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
            return keyFactory
                    .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the signature from the server matches the computed
     * signature on the data. Returns true if the data is correctly signed.
     * 
     * @param publicKey
     *            public key associated with the developer account
     * @param signedData
     *            signed data from server
     * @param signature
     *            server signature
     * @return true if the data and signature match
     */
    public static boolean verify(PublicKey publicKey, String signedData,
            String signature) {
        if (Constans.DEBUG) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "signature: " + signature);
        }
        Signature sig;
        try {
            sig = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
            sig.initVerify(publicKey);
            sig.update(signedData.getBytes());
            if (!sig.verify(Base64.decode(signature))) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Signature verification failed.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException.");
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Signature exception.");
        } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you only restoring "Subscriptions" or it also contains "In App products"?

Comment: can you please eloberate what you mean to say.

Comment: Hi Mohsin sorry i am getting purchase history but purchase token and developerpayload in json is returning null value.

Answer (score 3):

Run your app in RELEASE mode and also debug mode as false in Manisfest file.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to purchase the products, your purchase the product flow should be like this:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 1001,mPurchaseFinishedListener,finalBase64);
```

When you are trying to purchase the subscriptions, your purchase flow should be like this

```
mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 1002,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener,finalBase64);
```